# Android Room - Странные результаты

Tags: java, android, android-room

У меня есть Room таблица

```
@Entity(tableName = "identities")
public class Identity {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "identities_id")
@SerializedName(value = "identities_id")
public long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "identities_rid")
@SerializedName(value = "identities_rid")
public Long rid = -1L;

@ColumnInfo(name = "identities_created_at")
@SerializedName(value = "identities_created_at")
public Long created_at = 0L;

@ColumnInfo(name = "identities_updated_at")
@SerializedName(value = "identities_updated_at")
public Long updated_at = 0L;

@ColumnInfo(name = "identities_deleted_at")
@SerializedName(value = "identities_deleted_at")
public Long deleted_at = 0L;
```

}

Когда я делаю запрос на получение удаленных значений (deleted_at <> 0), то мне отдает ВСЕ результаты (что неправильно), и когда я делаю запрос на получение не-удаленных результатов (deleted_at = 0), то выдает ноль результатов, что тоже неправильно. Почему SQLite ведет себя так странно? Или я чего-то не учёл в составлении запроса? По умолчанию эта колонка при создании ставится равной 0, и нигде не изменяется.

[image: нет результатов]
[image: есть результаты]

Comment: Наверное записывать не так надо. Попробуйте или кавычки вокруг имени колонки убрать или добавить одиночные кавычки вокруг значения `0`

Comment: Кавычки там для UI, который делает запросы в БД. Думаю, что проблемы с ним т.к. теперь возвращает нужные данные.